# directional arrows beneath axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R & ggplot2: How to get arrows under the axis label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160706/r-ggplot2-how-to-get-arrows-under-the-axis-label)

How do we make `ggplot2` or base `r` produce arrows showing the direction of the axis?

e.g.

[image]

Comment: How complex are your plots?  That is, could you use base graphics instead?  It's easier to put things outside the axis using base (at least for us mortals who don't know grid).

Comment: base solutions may work if they are much more achievable

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full blown example I used for my microeconomics class to generate supply and demand curves. Notice the lines, where I am generating X and Y axes. I usually work with R Studio. It makes a lot easier to run scripts, analyze data structures and see graphs. Hope this helps.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("grid")

funcs <- list(function(x) return (200-0.02*x),function(x) return (200-0.04*x),             function(x) return (10))
#cols <-heat.colors(5,1)
p <-ggplot()+xlim(c(-10,15000))+ylim(c(-10,210))+xlab("Quantity")+ylab("Price")

# Y-axis
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=-10,xend=0,yend=210),         arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.2,"cm")))

# X-axis
p <- p +     geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=15000,yend=0),arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.2,"cm")))

# Horizontal segment representing optimal quantity 4750
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=105,xend=4750,yend=105),lty=2, col="gray60")

# Vertical segment representing optimal price i.e $105
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x=4750,y=0,xend=4750,yend=105), lty=2, col="gray60")

# Marginal Revenue curve label
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x=4750,y=0, vjust=5), col="gray60", label="MR")

# Marginal Cost curve label
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x=15000,y=10, vjust=-1), col="gray60", label="MC")

# Demand curve label
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x=10000,y=0, vjust=4), col="gray60", label="D")

# Optimal Quantity label.
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x=4750,y=0, hjust=1, vjust=1.5), col="gray60", label="Qm", size=3)

# Optimal Quantity
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x=4750,y=0,  hjust=1, vjust=3), col="gray60", label="(4750)", size=3)

# Optimal Price label
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x=0,y=105, hjust=1, vjust=-2.5), col="gray60", label="Pm", size=3)

#Optimal price
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x=0,y=105,  hjust=1, vjust=-1), col="gray60", label="($105)", size=3)

for(i in 1:length(funcs))
  p <- p + stat_function(aes(y=0),fun = funcs[[i]],          arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.2,"cm")))

# Change in marginal cost due to subsidy.
p <- p + stat_function(aes(y=0),fun = function(x) return(5), lty=2,      arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.2,"cm")))
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x=15000,y=5, hjust=-1), col="gray60", label="MC_NEW", size=4)

# Horizontal segment representing optimal quantity 4750
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=102.5,xend=4875,yend=102.5),lty=2, col="gray60")
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x=4875,y=0,xend=4875,yend=102.5), lty=2, col="gray60")

# Optimal Price label
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x=0,y=105, hjust=.51, vjust=2.5), col="gray60", label="Pm_NEW",     size=3)

#Optimal price
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x=0,y=105,  hjust=.51, vjust=4.0), col="gray60", label="($102.50)", size=3)

# Optimal Quantity label.
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x=4750,y=0, vjust=1.5, hjust=-.5), col="gray60", label="Qm_NEW", size=3)

# Optimal Quantity
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x=4750,y=0,   vjust=3, hjust=-1), col="gray60", label="(4875)",     size=3)
print(p)
```

Comment: thank you for your help, i thought on the `geom_segment` approach but I was hoping to get them outside the plotting area.