# line from -infinity to infinity with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot something like this with ggplot2

[image]

I can do this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_hline(yintercept=1) + 
  ylab("Likelihood") + 
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

But I still need to add the line with -infinity 0 and infinity

Comment: FYI in the development version of *ggplot2* you can add arrows onto axis lines.  If you have an x axis you can use something like `axis.line.x = element_line(arrow = arrow(ends = "both"))` in `theme`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a little help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7165019/5619526), and a somewhat hacky solution, we can come up with something:

```
ggplot() + geom_hline(yintercept=1) + 
    ylab("Likelihood") + 
    xlab('')+
    theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
          panel.background = element_blank())+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-5,0,5),
                       labels = c(expression(-infinity), 0, expression(infinity)),
                       limits = c(-5,5))+
    geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = Inf, y = -1, yend = -1),
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(.2, 'cm')))+
    geom_segment(aes(x = Inf, xend = -Inf, y = -1, yend = -1),
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(.2, 'cm')))+
    ylim(c(-1,3))
```

[image]